# Python - automatically apply Excel filters to .csv files/method to convert hh:mm:ss time string to integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv

I have a ton of VOIP analytics to process, all in .csv format.

All calls are formatted as rows, and I need to isolate rows with cells that match the strings "Answered" and "Terminating", and with call duration <= 00:00:30.

I've been combing through Python libraries to find one that can quickly and easily apply the necessary filters *and* work with that funky time format so I never have to actually open the .csv itself, but with mixed success. If I knew a quick way to convert that time string into an integer, that would help a lot as well.

What's the best library and method to use in this situation? Currently working with Python 3.

Checked xlsxwriter, no dice since it's write-only. Currently looking at Pandas and openpyxl, but it's looking murky.

Comment: 1) Not sure why you would think spreadsheet libraries would work for CSV. CSV is a text format, spreadsheet files are binary(more or less). 2) There is nothing funky about `00:00:30` is a perfectly acceptable time format. 3) You will need to get into the file at some point. 4) Why not just use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) at command line to filter a CSV and capture all rows with `time <= 00:00:30`.

```
cat time_select.csv
id,time_val
1,00:00:01
2,00:00:02
3,00:00:03
4,00:00:04
5,00:00:05
6,00:00:06
7,00:00:07
8,00:00:08
9,00:00:09
10,00:00:10
...
50,00:00:50
51,00:00:51
52,00:00:52
53,00:00:53
54,00:00:54
55,00:00:55
56,00:00:56
57,00:00:57
58,00:00:58
59,00:00:59


mlr --csv filter 'strptime($time_val, "%H:%M:%S") <= strptime("00:00:30", "%H:%M:%S")' time_select.csv > time_filtered.csv

cat time_filtered.csv 
id,time_val
1,00:00:01
2,00:00:02
3,00:00:03
4,00:00:04
5,00:00:05
6,00:00:06
7,00:00:07
8,00:00:08
9,00:00:09
10,00:00:10
11,00:00:11
12,00:00:12
13,00:00:13
14,00:00:14
15,00:00:15
16,00:00:16
17,00:00:17
18,00:00:18
19,00:00:19
20,00:00:20
21,00:00:21
22,00:00:22
23,00:00:23
24,00:00:24
25,00:00:25
26,00:00:26
27,00:00:27
28,00:00:28
29,00:00:29
30,00:00:30
```